# JQuery Mobile Override Change Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

What I trying to accomplish is not record certain pages in the history, so the back button will not take you back to the previous page.

For example, if the page is the login page or register page, do not record it, else record the page :

```
function changePage(page)
if(page == 'login' || page == 'register') {

$.mobile.changePage( "#" + page , {
    transition: "pop",
    reverse: false,
    changeHash: false
});

} else {
$.mobile.changePage( "#" + page, {
    transition: "pop",
    reverse: true,
    changeHash: true
});
}

}//end change page
```

But I want to ovveride the mobile.changePage function in a global way so it checks each the function is called. Can anyone give me any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all calls to `changePage()` in your code with a custom function `myChangePage()` and extend jQuery Mobile as shown below:

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit', function(){

  $.mobile.myChangePage = function(page, options){

    if ($.inArray(page.substr(1), ['login', 'register']))
    {
      $.extend(options, {
        reverse: false,
        changeHash: false
      });
    }

    $.mobile.changePage(page, options);

  };
});
```

Example usage:

```
$.mobile.myChangePage('#login');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would save the function of change page to a variable then if in some instances you don't need to override the function you can proxy right back to the function:

```
var cp = $.mobile.changePage;
$.mobile.changePage = function(to, options) {
    if(youdontneedtoverride) {
        cp(to, options);
    } else {
        ....
    }
}
```